# How to change velocity template in Intellij for catch statement

Tags: java, intellij-idea, apache-velocity

I want to print in catch block directly with logger like:

Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

I checked Velocity template in Settings - File and Code Templates for Catch Statement body

By Default it is given with

```
${EXCEPTION}.printStackTrace()
```

Tried changing with:

```
Logger.getLogger(${NAME}.class.getName()).log(LEVEL.INFO,${EXCEPTION}.printStackTrace(),${EXCEPTION});
```

but the Logger statement is getting wrong while, NAME is not picking class Name as provided in guidelines: 
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-template-variables.html

Want to automatically put logger statement in catch block whenever  I am using try-catch block or try with resources block to catch such that it has like:

```
Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use **${NAME}** variable in `Code Templates` yet. You may try to use the following construction to get the class name:

```
Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(LEVEL.INFO,${EXCEPTION}.printStackTrace(),${EXCEPTION});
```

There is a similar request on JetBrains issues tracker: [IDEA-55300](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-55300)